# Как выбирать через функцию input () одну из двух других функций?

Tags: python

Изучаю питон3. Как сделать, чтобы можно было по выбору через функцию `input()`  выбирать нужный блок, и как сделать что бы эти блоки были изолированы друг от друга?

```
def kvadrat():
    a = int(input("введите число: ")
    return a **2
s = kvadrat()
print(s)
def pramoygolnik():
    a = int(input("введите число"))
    b = int(input("введите число"))
    return a * b
n = pramoygolnik()
print(n)
```

Comment: Какой блок? Что значит "изолированы"? Опишите подробнее, как должен выглядет процесс.

Comment: С помощью простого `if`

Comment: есть 2 разные функции которые выполняют разную задачу, хочу с помощью функции  input() выбирать одну из них, 2 не должна быть загружена

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько моментов, на которые стоит обратить внимание:

1. ввод данных пользователем не стоит смешивать с функцией расчета площади
2. квадрат - частный случай прямоугольника, нет смысла писать отдельную функцию расчета площади для квадрата
3. пользователь может ввести строку или вещественное число. При попытке преобразовать такой ввод к целому возникнет исключение, которое следует обработать
4. Ввод целого числа пользователем можно оформить в виде функции

---

Пример:

```
def input_int(prompt):
    ret = 0
    while ret <= 0:
        try:
            ret = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Ошибка ввода!")
    return ret

def calc_rect_area(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
    return a * b

a = input_int("введите целое число больше нуля: ")
b = input_int("введите целое число больше нуля: ")

area_rect = calc_rect_area(a, b)
area_square = calc_rect_area(a)
```